# using awk to append fields of one file to another

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to append each line of one file (database) to the end of another to use in an html table using awk. I keep getting a syntax error at the '}' and not sure why.

```
cat cds.db | sort -t':' -k4 | awk -F':' '{for i in $(cat cds.db) do echo "<tr><td align=left> $2 </td><td align=left> $1 </td><td align=right> $4 </td></tr>" }' >>cds.html done
```

Comment: The `awk` code does have several issues.  Would you show a few lines from `cds.db` and what you would like the output from those lines to look like?

Comment: this is a few lines from the file: Morrison, Van:Astral Weeks:Warner Bros:1968 \n
McKennet, Loreena:Book of Secrets:Warner Bros:1997\n
Indigo Girls:Shaming of the Sun:Epic:1997 \n
I want the output to be the the title, artist, year. I'm very new to awk and I know awk is very particular about syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this input file:

```
$ cat cds.db
Morrison, Van:Astral Weeks:Warner Bros:1968
McKennet, Loreena:Book of Secrets:Warner Bros:1997
Indigo Girls:Shaming of the Sun:Epic:1997
```

To sort by year and reorder the fields:

```
$ sort -t: -k4 cds.db | awk -F: '{print $2":"$1":"$4 }' 
Astral Weeks:Morrison, Van:1968
Shaming of the Sun:Indigo Girls:1997
Book of Secrets:McKennet, Loreena:1997
```

Notes:

- The colon (`:`) is not shell-active.  Consequently, there are no special quoting requirements for it.
- `awk` implicitly loops over every line of input.  So, it is not necessary to have a `for` loop to read in the lines.
- For output, `awk` has `print` and `printf` statements.  It has no `echo`.
- The above script assumes that you want a colon as the field separator on output.  If not, the `print` statement can be adjusted.

#### Alternative using the output field separator

If the arguments to `print` are separated by commas, then, upon printing, `awk` inserts between them the output field separator, `OFS`.  The following uses this approach and generates the same output as above:

```
sort -t: -k4 cds.db | awk -F: -v OFS=: '{print $2,$1,$4 }'
```